# How to integrate $ y\cos^4x$ over a disk?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to integrate
$$\int_D y\cos^4x \, \mathrm dx \mathrm dy$$
where $D=\{(x,y)\in R^2;x^2+y^2<\pi\}.$
I'm thinking using the polar coordinates but doing so the integral would become,

$$\int_D \rho \sin\theta\cos^4(\rho \cos\theta)\ \, \mathrm d\theta \mathrm d\rho$$

and $D=\{(\rho,\theta)\in R^2;\rho^2<\pi,0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi\}$ which is even more difficult. Can someone explain me how to solve the exercise?

The professor says that this should have a quick resolution, so probably there is something I'm missing, please help me

Comment: What happens if you write $(x,y)=(x’,-y’)$?

Comment: The function is odd on $y$ , and the domain is symmetric with respect to $y$: this means that the integral is $0$.

Comment: @Crostul Ok this is exactly the quick resolution I mentioned, but I can use the odd property because D is centered in (0,0) , right?